Use Python to control json.dump() format with kwarg "default="?
In Python I have to keep dumping to a storage file an array of user data consisting of JSON objects (simple format: [{}, {}...]). As the program captures and records user data, the array [] will increase potentially into the small thousands of objects. Each object {} consists of up to about fifty key_value pairs.
How would I write a custom function for json.dump() using the native "default=" kwarg that will start each object on a new line, and add an extra linespace between? Using the "indent=" kwarg to pretty-print the array makes a file that is too long vertically, and without that kwarg I get a dense mass of objects hard to read.
To illustrate the problem, take a much shorter array.
example = [{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3,}, {"d":1, "e":2, "f":3,}, {"g":1, "h":2, "i":3}, {"j":6, "k":7, "l":8}]
Without using indent, the output to my .json file is too compact.
[{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}, {"d": 1, "e": 2, "f": 3}, {"g": 1, "h": 2, "i": 3}, {"j": 6, "k": 7, "l": 8}]

If I use indent, I get a narrow vertical column.
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
  },
  {
    "d": 1,
    "e": 2,
    "f": 3
  },
  {
    "g": 1,
    "h": 2,
    "i": 3
  },
  {
    "j": 6,
    "k": 7,
    "l": 8
  }
]

To minimize whitespace while maintaining readability, I want output in this format (here arranged manually).
[
    {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3},

    {"d": 1, "e": 2, "f": 3},

    {"g": 1, "h": 2, "i": 3}, 

    {"j": 6, "k": 7, "l": 8}
]

When each object holds up to fifty key:value pairs, this format, even with wrapping, will achieve both ends. I'm surprised the method provides no such option.
But I can't find enough info on the nuts and bolts of JSON code to impose newlines and extra linespaces within the existing json.dump() method. Any help?

Why are you surprised? There's nothing like this in JavaScript or PHP, either. Like Python, they only provide the choice between one line and everything on a new line. Detailed formatting control is not an option.

If your top-level object is an array, consider the JSON Lines (JSONL) format instead. It is literally one JSON object per line with no [] on the outside. The advantage is that you can append to JSONL easily without rewriting the whole file, which is great for efficiency. It’s also easy to read: just for line in file: json.loads(line).

If you're trying to minimise whitespace, why is there a newline between each dictionary in the output? It's certainly not a functional requirement

@SIGHUP: With the much longer dictionaries in my real program, the extra linespaces are a relatively small proportion of total space—worth it for the gain in readability.

The answers all underscore Barmar's and diggusbickus's point that what I wanted to do cannot be done natively but has to be achieved by a workaround. I tested user24714692's snippet and it worked perfectly, creating a JSON file that json.load() could load. SIGHUP's I didn't test, as I start with unindented dictionaries and have to write them to file. I spent part of today reading documentation on JSON Lines. In the end, the advantage of being able to append rather than overwrite the entire datafile every time drew me to @nneonneo's solution.

If your top-level object is an array, consider the JSON Lines (JSONL) format instead. It is literally one JSON object per line with no [] on the outside. The advantage is that you can append to JSONL easily without rewriting the whole file, which is great for efficiency - calling dump to dump an ever-expanding array will incur linear slowdown per dump (overall quadratic time!), whereas appending to a JSON Lines file is constant-time (overall linear time for all records).
To append new objects to a JSON Lines file:
with open("output.jsonl", "a") as outf:
    json.dump(new_record, outf)
    outf.write("\n")

To read all records from a JSON Lines file:
with open("output.jsonl", "r") as inf:
    for row in inf:
        obj = json.loads(row)
        # then process obj or append it to a list, etc.


Very helpful suggestion. For my situation, however, I found that I have to append new objects using JSON Lines's own special syntax, opening with "with jsonlines.open(file, mode='a') as writer:" and then writing with "writer.write(new_obj)". After writing the new obj to file, this automatically sets up a new numbered line with the cursor in it, ready to receive another object. JSON's "json.dump()" just appends new objs to the existing line—not quite the result I was hoping to get.

You can use json module with dumps():
import json


def _dump_one(example, p):
    with open(p, 'w') as f:
        f.write('[\n')
        for i, e in enumerate(example):
            s = json.dumps(e)
            f.write(f'\t{s}')
            if i < len(example) - 1:
                f.write(',\n\n')
            else:
                f.write('\n')
        f.write(']\n')


example = [
    {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3},
    {"d": 1, "e": 2, "f": 3},
    {"g": 1, "h": 2, "i": 3},
    {"j": 6, "k": 7, "l": 8}
]

_dump_one(example, 'file.json')



You can also write() it only once:
import json


def _dump_two(example, p):
    res = '[\n'
    for i, e in enumerate(example):
        s = json.dumps(e)
        res += f'\t{s}'
        if i < len(example) - 1:
            res += ',\n\n'
        else:
            res += '\n'
    res += ']\n'

    with open(p, 'w') as f:
        f.write(res)


example = [
    {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3},
    {"d": 1, "e": 2, "f": 3},
    {"g": 1, "h": 2, "i": 3},
    {"j": 6, "k": 7, "l": 8}
]

_dump_two(example, 'file.json')




How would I write a custom function for json.dump() using the native "default=" kwarg that will start each object on a new line, and add an extra linespace between?

you can't. default would only apply to values not to "rows", and even then your values are serializable

If specified, default should be a function that gets called for objects that can’t otherwise be serialized − json module docs


You could use json.dumps() to format the individual dictionaries and add the formatted output to a list. You can subsequently use str.join() to give you the output format you require.
import json

a = [
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
  },
  {
    "d": 1,
    "e": 2,
    "f": 3
  },
  {
    "g": 1,
    "h": 2,
    "i": 3
  },
  {
    "j": 6,
    "k": 7,
    "l": 8
  }
]

d = [json.dumps(_d) for _d in a]

print("[\n\t" + ",\n\n\t".join(d) + "\n]")

Output:
[
        {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3},

        {"d": 1, "e": 2, "f": 3},

        {"g": 1, "h": 2, "i": 3},

        {"j": 6, "k": 7, "l": 8}
]

